# Splitting time series with dummies

Tags: time-series

I'm doing a linear regression for corporate default rates. However, there is a big financial crisis (2008) in the middle of my time series. You can see the plot below. In order to fit a linear regression to ir, my professor's idea was to use dummies and split the time series for pre and post crisis and examine the significance of the independent variables (GDP growth, interest rate, debt/GDP) on the default rate in the two situations.

So the basic idea is creating a dummy for each variable, multiply them with the dummy and this way use twice as many variables.

The part I do not completely understand if I should use two series of dummies (2 times 3) and completely split the time series this way, or let one set of the variables be relevant for the whole series?

Here are my two equations, which I'm trying to decide between:

defrate = c + b(1)* **d1** * Y1 + b(2)* **d1** * Y2 + b(3)* **d1** * Y3 + b(4)*Y1 + b(5)*Y2 + b(6)*Y3

or

defrate = c + b(1)* **d1** * Y1 + b(2)* **d1** * Y2 + b(3)* **d1** * Y3 + b(4)* **d2** * Y1 + b(5)* **d2** * Y2 + b(6)* **d2** * Y3

where d1 is a dummy that is 1 for post-crisis values, and 0 for others

d2 is the opposite, 0 for post crisis values, 1 for values before that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between your two models. b(4) - b(6) are the same in two models. They are slopes for before crisis. b(1) - b(3) in the first model is the change of slopes post crisis vs pre crisis. b(1) - b(3) in the second model are slopes for post crisis. So b(1) in second model = b(1) + b(4) in the first model. It is true for b(2) and b(3) also.

In your model d1 as main effect should be in the model.

Let assume you fit the first model with d1 as main effect. Then you have 8 parameters, and it equals to fit two models. The benefit of fitting one model instead of two is you can check if there are redundant parameters (over-fitting?). In your case, you can check if b(4) - b(6) are significant or not. If not, you can consider to exclude it from the model. For example, if b(4) is not significant and is excluded, it means the slope of Y1 is the same during pre- and post-crisis.

Comment: makes sense, I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: well, actually the two models differ in reality. Using only one dummy proved to produce a better model

Comment: You got the different $R^2$ from two models?

Comment: yes, the adjusted   R2 is 0,953647 with one dummy, 0,866372 with two. AIC is -171 and -102 respectively

Comment: What software did you use? Both models gave 7 estimates of parameters?

Comment: Yes, I got the same significant variables, but with differenc koefficients. I used gretl.

Comment: I am not familiar with gretl. How many regression coefficients you got in two models?

Comment: I know this is old, but I am learning Econometrics now and wanted to make sure I'm understanding things right: Wasn't the adjusted R^2 supposed to be lower for the second model anyway because of more variables?

Comment: These two models have no any difference in math. As in the Answer, b(4) - b(6) are exact the same in two models. For b(1) - b(3), they are the same things, but express in different way. For example, you can say that weight of person A is 150 pounds and person B is 160 pounds you can also say that person A is 150 pounds and person B is 10 pounds heavier than person A. So the $R^2$ from two models should be exactly the same.